# Tailwind Inline Custom Breakpoint

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a project that has custom "desktop", "tablet", and "mobile" breakpoints, however I have a page where I want to do a 4th one-off breakpoint. I don't want to commit it to the overall styles page just yet and I was wondering if there was a way to define the breakpoint "inline" on the className? ie something like this:

```
<div className="grid  desktop:grid-cols-4 [1120px]:grid-col-3 tablet:grid-cols-2...
```

Comment: You can update the tailwind.config.js and add your breakpoints

Comment: I wanted to try and avoid this right now as this might be a one-off example and never used again in the app.

Comment: In that case, you might need to create a separate external css file and link it to your app.js. It won't break the existing code and will get the job done. Tailwind CSS is pretty nifty when it comes to breakpoints though.. `2xl:` breakpoint does `1440px` out of the box I think

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way from tailwind docs

> Arbitrary values If you need to use a one-off breakpoint that doesn’t
> make sense to include in your theme, use the min or max modifiers to
> generate a custom breakpoint on the fly using any arbitrary value.

```
<div class="min-[320px]:text-center max-[600px]:bg-sky-300">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

source:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#arbitrary-values

(sometimes you have to restart the server to see that applied properly)

Answer (score 1):

Acording to this Discussion Issue you can create custom breakpoints inline

```html
<div class="h-64 bg-red-500 [@media(min-width:711px)]:bg-green-500"></div>
```

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/8261#discussioncomment-3251527

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class for one-off breakpoint styling using tailwind class with `@screen` and `@apply`. The [styling method](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors) could be different with different CSS preprocessor.

Example using scss:

```
.one-off {
  @apply w-full;

  @media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    @apply w-1/4
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1120px) {
    @apply w-2/4
  }

  @screen mobile {
    @apply grid-cols-1;
  }
  @screen tablet {
    @apply grid-cols-2;
  }
  @screen desktop {
    @apply grid-cols-4;
  }
}
```